# Problem with D-Link DWA171 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, d-link

I have a problem with an external network card D-LINK DWA-171 - model C on Ubuntu 16.04

When trying to compile official drivers downloaded from https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-171 an error occurs

```
praca@Praca:~/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821
CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/build M=/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic'
CC [M]  /home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                from /home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/include/drv_types.h:27,
                from /home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/include/osdep_service_linux.h:299:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^
/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/include/osdep_service_linux.h:300:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
init_timer(ptimer);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: polecenia dla obiektu '/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/core/rtw_cmd.o' nie powiodły się
make[2]: *** [/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525/core/rtw_cmd.o] Błąd 1
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/praca/Pobrane/20180518_DWA-171C_RTL8811CU_Linux_driver_v5.2.15.2/rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.15.2_27778.20180515_COEX20171114-2525] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic'
Makefile:1856: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

So I found another solutions 
http://startusingubuntu.blogspot.com/2014/08/install-driver-for-d-link-dwd-171.html 
However, after making the whole manual, the external network card still does not work.

I was also interested in the mention in readme attached to the official drivers

```
Please note that DWA-171C support auto install driver function in Windwos OS,
user should exit Flash disk mode(default) to active adapter mode.
```

The `lsusb` command also finds nothing with the name "D-Link".

```
praca@Praca:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1d57:0005 Xenta Wireless Receiver (Keyboard and Mouse)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0c21 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

PS. External network card works perfectly on Windows10

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.